# How to insert mysql data into perl graph (Editted)

Tags: perl, gd-graph

So my task is creating a graph of the data that is inside MySQL table (which is around 41 data with 7 rows) . I only did a basic graph  ... so is it possible for me to even create a graph using the data that is inside MySQL table using perl script.

sorry for the lack of codding though since i dont even know how to create a perl graph using MySQL data

Edit

i tried doing the graph but it seems that the data isnt showing up as it attended . it only shown only an empty graph and the values start with a negative for some reason... is there something that i did wrong ?

my sql table

```
create table Top_1 (
CPU_User float, CPU_System float, CPU_Waiting float);
```

my script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;
use GD::Graph::bars;
use GD::Graph::Data;


my $username = "root";
my $password = "";
my $db = "Top_Data_1";
my $host = "127.0.0.1";
my $port = "3306";

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$db;host=$host;port=$port";
my %attr = (PrintError=>0,RaiseError=>1 );
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username,$password,\%attr) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('CPU_User, CPU_System, CPU_Waiting from Top_1');
$sth->execute();
my @row;
while ( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {

    print "this is CPU_User\n";
    print "$row[0]\n";

    print "this is CPU_System \n";
    print "$row[1]\n";

    print "this is CPU_Waiting \n";
    print "$row[2]\n";


                    }

my $data = GD::Graph::Data->new([ 

["8 am","10 pm","12 pm"],
['$row[0]'],
['$row[1]'],
['$row[2]'],
]) or die GD::Graph::Data->error;  

my $graph = GD::Graph::bars->new;

$graph->set( 
    x_label         => 'File_Name',
    y_label         => 'Value',
    title           => 'TOP CPU DISPLAY',

    x_labels_vertical => 1,
    bar_spacing => 10,
    bar_width => 3,
    long_ticks => 1,

    ) or die $graph->error;

$graph->set_legend_font(GD::gdMediumBoldFont);
$graph->set_legend('CPU USER','CPU_System','CPU_Waiting');

$graph->plot($data) or die $graph->error;

my $file = 'bars.png';
print "Your Picture Has Been Added To Your Directory\n";
open(my $out, '>', $file) or die "Cannot open '$file' for write: $!";

binmode $out;
print $out $graph->gd->png;
close $out;

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: Is it web-based?

Comment: @Bruce no its not a web based

Comment: How are you running the script - command line, also Linux or Windows?

Comment: im using linux :U @Bruce

Comment: So you are executing the script via the command line?

Comment: @Bruce im using script (perl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure is not correct.

Not sure of your database table, but if you have the time field in it then something like below should work.

```
    my $data = GD::Graph::Data->new();
    my $sth = $dbh_mysql->prepare('SELECT hour, CPU_USER, CPU_System, CPU_Waiting FROM top1');
    $sth->execute();
    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) 
    {
        $data->add_point(@row);
    }
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply ... this works wonders .. thank u  @Bruce

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to do. One can use DBI to get data from MySQL. Then, you can arrange the data into a format to graph it using a graphing library. I have used GD::Graph and is easy to use.

Links:
MySQL: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql
Graph: https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph

Comment: can u look at  my code if there is anything wrong with it ?? there is no error but the graph is shown with the y values start with a negative number